# How to configure Log4j for Selenium WebDriverManager? An log4j error occurres

Tags: java, xml, webdriver, log4j

This package has an error - `io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Preferences`. I don't understand how should I configure `log4j.xml` file to support this internal logger. I don't need this WebDriverManager logger at all. Just a trace level for my project needs.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Preferences).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

```
package io.github.bonigarcia.wdm;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Preferences {
    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    static final String TTL = "-ttl";
    java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs = java.util.prefs.Preferences.userNodeForPackage(WebDriverManager.class);
```

I tried to go through few manuals - how to configure `log4j.xml` properly. And also tired to configure `log4j.properties` file.

Right now `log4j.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

> How should I add an `WARN appender` for `io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Preferences`? Or how should I exclude WebDriverManagers logger?

Answer (score 0):

Set this dependency in `pom.xml` file to exclude SLF4J Errors:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.28</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```